# Flutter The method 'User' isn't defined for the type '_LeaveApplicationState'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app using Flutter and Firebase for the backend. I was Following a tutorial guide but when I have written the code am getting two types of errors, the first one being;
"The method 'User' isn't defined for the type '_LeaveApplicationState' "

```
class LeaveApplication extends StatefulWidget {
  const LeaveApplication({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LeaveApplicationState createState() => _LeaveApplicationState();
}

class _LeaveApplicationState extends State<LeaveApplication> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final controllerFirstName = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'Apply For Work Leave',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                //rest of code....

                  child: MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      final user = **User**(
                        fname: controllerFirstName.text,
                        lname: controllerLastName.text,
                        email: controllerEmail.text,
                        phoneno: int.parse(controllerPhoneNo.text),
                        leave: controllerLeaveType,
                        duration: controllerDuration.text,
                      );

                      Navigator.pop(context);

                      createUser(user);

                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(content: Text('Request Sent')),
                        );
                      }
                    },
             
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future createUser(**User** user) async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('employees').doc();
    user.id = docUser.id;

    final json = user.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
}
```

the second error is "Undefined class 'User'."
the errors arise in the areas which are in bold/asterisk.
I want the user who has logged in to be able to put in details and send them to firebase datebase. Can anyone help

Comment: Are you imported User class? or can you add User class details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing your user model class this should work fine i will sujjest you to change the name of your user class to something else because firebase also have a user class might you had imported that one please recheck again and let me know if this works

Comment: even if changed it still wont' work

Comment: pleaseprovide youre code i mean model class